# Calculating the mean of 3 columns in data frame

Tags: r

I have 3 data frames and they are just replicates. So I want to bind them and calculate the mean of each fraction.

Three data frames:

Nr.1

```
> dput(head(tbl_gel1))
structure(list(Name = c("yal003w", "yal005c", "yal012w", "yal016w", 
"yal035w", "yal038w"), `1_1` = c(1.08346521189121, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `1_10` = c(0.267721905361376, 1.43303883148383, 1.61684304894131, 
NA, NA, NA), `1_11` = c(0.189487668138674, 0.75522363065885, 
1, NA, NA, NA), `1_12` = c(NA, 1.01340492119247, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), `1_13` = c(0.374782308020683, 0.945489433731933, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.0317297633029047), `1_14` = c(0.437488212634424, 1.18763709680314, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.0278039649538794), `1_15` = c(1, 0.963283876302253, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.101985769564935), `1_16` = c(0.933864874212228, 
0.534233379286527, NA, NA, NA, 0.216767470594226), `1_17` = c(1, 
0.665519263271478, NA, NA, 1, 1), `1_18` = c(0.666036574750145, 
0.570465125348879, NA, NA, NA, 1.42894349812116), `1_19` = c(0.514337131747938, 
0.23204076838128, NA, NA, 1, 1.2521214021452), `1_2` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `1_20` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.40803677399372), `1_21` = c(1.09990599806138, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.04631699593704), `1_22` = c(1.26442418472118, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.928872017485782), `1_23` = c(1.11596921281805, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, 0.34698227364696), `1_24` = c(0.754496014447251, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, 0.222234793614252), `1_3` = c(6.29254185223621, 
NA, NA, 0.693642968439352, NA, NA), `1_4` = c(1.36347593974479, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), `1_5` = c(0.765885344543765, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA), `1_6` = c(0.238118001668604, 0.679584207611477, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `1_7` = c(0.847897771442355, 0.277348019879946, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), `1_8` = c(0.356154192700505, 1, 0.409523853881517, 
NA, NA, NA), `1_9` = c(0.180109142324181, 1, 0.578310191227172, 
NA, NA, 0.093113736249161)), .Names = c("Name", "1_1", "1_10", 
"1_11", "1_12", "1_13", "1_14", "1_15", "1_16", "1_17", "1_18", 
"1_19", "1_2", "1_20", "1_21", "1_22", "1_23", "1_24", "1_3", 
"1_4", "1_5", "1_6", "1_7", "1_8", "1_9"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Nr. 2

```
> dput(head(tbl_gel2))
structure(list(Name = c("yal003w", "yal005c", "yal012w", "yal016w", 
"yal035w", "yal038w"), `2_1` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `2_2` = c(1.0548947840373, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `2_3` = c(1.61794716486303, 0.346821796129205, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `2_4` = c(1, NA, NA, 0.378254379051086, NA, 
NA), `2_5` = c(0.670710809411423, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), `2_6` = c(0.313872585645673, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2_7` = c(0.299293639466945, 0.13920907824675, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `2_8` = c(0.311431376422469, 0.511742245543671, 
0.342807141055383, NA, NA, NA), `2_9` = c(0.243672215177189, 
1, 0.689138745271004, NA, NA, 0.0540861571772987), `2_10` = c(0.154732102234279, 
1.08973258347909, 1, NA, NA, NA), `2_11` = c(0.149365726324845, 
1.1210733533474, 1.0427649268992, NA, NA, 0.0955468461925663), 
    `2_12` = c(0.153741630869067, 2.96276072446013, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA), `2_13` = c(0.629371115599316, 0.952868912207058, 0.0771105403237483, 
    NA, NA, 0.0885212695236819), `2_14` = c(0.907644486740723, 
    1.43000783337778, NA, NA, NA, 0.138102409899801), `2_15` = c(1.09683345304359, 
    0.423641943213571, NA, NA, NA, 0.255699738225622), `2_16` = c(0.913095779338154, 
    0.510977400533081, NA, NA, 0.520556617688936, 0.284898552722227
    ), `2_17` = c(0.935941553863477, 0.388225948821767, NA, NA, 
    1.14984991998928, 1), `2_18` = c(2.21746156904543, 0.642743615867438, 
    NA, NA, NA, 2.22716071647178), `2_19` = c(0.500618035526774, 
    0.282924681750454, NA, NA, NA, 1), `2_20` = c(0.701627311828743, 
    0.254001731153973, NA, NA, 1, 1.15996914621286), `2_21` = c(1.97359874904275, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1.67526802494991, 1.38709456754353), `2_22` = c(2.09198896289293, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.921672834103247), `2_23` = c(1.18791465369551, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.576309066193914), `2_24` = c(0.473199477125101, 
    0.176144702328764, NA, NA, 1, 0.130236848112641)), .Names = c("Name", 
"2_1", "2_2", "2_3", "2_4", "2_5", "2_6", "2_7", "2_8", "2_9", 
"2_10", "2_11", "2_12", "2_13", "2_14", "2_15", "2_16", "2_17", 
"2_18", "2_19", "2_20", "2_21", "2_22", "2_23", "2_24"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Nr.3

```
> dput(head(tbl_gel3))
structure(list(Name = c("yal003w", "yal005c", "yal012w", "yal016w", 
"yal035w", "yal038w"), `3_1` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `3_2` = c(1, 1.4605309655311, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `3_3` = c(1.74480713727388, 0.42825619952525, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `3_4` = c(1, 0.431712121875013, NA, 0.395182020245312, 
NA, NA), `3_5` = c(2.26247329056518, 0.644462177666441, NA, 1, 
NA, NA), `3_6` = c(0.619783374266709, 0.472094874244026, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), `3_7` = c(0.45731912574756, 0.176354321796083, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), `3_8` = c(0.271829278733367, 0.517232771669986, 
0.153774052052871, NA, NA, NA), `3_9` = c(0.141017619508583, 
1.41279969394534, 0.651948154271122, NA, NA, NA), `3_10` = c(NA, 
1.64435171100405, 0.998807430240956, NA, NA, NA), `3_11` = c(0.110046035477971, 
1.33684444261939, 1.25595310581771, NA, NA, 0.0236163735479745
), `3_12` = c(NA, 0.982250906830292, 0.39283619985401, NA, NA, 
0.0688303458902568), `3_13` = c(0.136798076436642, 0.55729642483448, 
0.176525038283566, NA, NA, 0.0251189412372225), `3_14` = c(0.316623893146817, 
1, NA, NA, NA, 0.0727823461722849), `3_15` = c(NA, 0.607991038574375, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.133968257432001), `3_16` = c(0.362994392402489, 
0.547183167896534, NA, NA, NA, 0.0777347708647245), `3_17` = c(1, 
0.116561118715651, NA, NA, 0.710972173471528, 1), `3_18` = c(NA, 
3.63330458071475, NA, NA, NA, 3.24019081192985), `3_19` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.46635222132474), `3_20` = c(0.452303676849426, 
0.0896715384025126, NA, NA, 1, 1), `3_21` = c(1.50169299468485, 
0.513442106966708, NA, NA, 1.45124841710635, 1.02529618467026
), `3_22` = c(0.565232592993276, 0.748536315065533, NA, NA, 2.9089322117881, 
0.782555457293307), `3_23` = c(1.62622280168665, 0.704926586534075, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.584486806995139), `3_24` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("Name", 
"3_1", "3_2", "3_3", "3_4", "3_5", "3_6", "3_7", "3_8", "3_9", 
"3_10", "3_11", "3_12", "3_13", "3_14", "3_15", "3_16", "3_17", 
"3_18", "3_19", "3_20", "3_21", "3_22", "3_23", "3_24"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used function below to bind them. There are different number of rows in each data frame and in some cases different names so in the final table should be more rows than in each of them.

```
mylist <- list(tbl_gel1,tbl_gel2,tbl_gel3)
tbl_all <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=T,by="Name",sort=F), 
                  mylist, accumulate=F)
```

Everything goes fine until this moment. 
Now I want to calculate the mean of each fraction (there is 24 fractions in total)

```
## Calculating the mean
tbl_all1 <- tbl_all[-1]
ind <- c(1, 25, 49)
tbl_mean <- cbind(tbl_all[1], sapply(0:23, function(i) rowMeans(tbl_all1[ind+i])))
```

There is something wrong with that function because `sum` of many rows gives `0`. That's definitely wrong because in `tbl_gel1` and others are only rows with atleast one number in any fraction.

If I take a look on `tbl_mean` I see that rows with `sum` of `0` are in the bottom.

Comment: I tried your code as it is... I am not getting any zero.. Either NA or value otherthan zero...

Comment: The problem is that you have only `head` of my data. The data is too big to do `dput`. I can upload somewhere if it's needed. Maybe you know any other function I can use to calculate the mean ?

Comment: Are you handling NAs? If not then try with `na.rm=TRUE` ...

Comment: There was a problem with NAs... it looks like I accidently changed the old script.

Comment: What is a "fraction"? That's not a term used to describe subsets of a matrix, so can you clarify? I'm also not sure that `cbind` is doing what you expect. `tbl_all[1]` is a single value. How could that bind to a list?

Comment: @ShaxiLiver - you problem solved or it is still there?

Comment: vrajs5 -> solved the problem. Carl -> each data frame which I try to bind has 24 fractions (columns with the values). Sorry for using such word but it's very common in my "enviroment".